# Redis in production with Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis

It may be trivial question but I need to be sure. I have made node/express app with redis connected as a cache manager. All works fine in dev environment. But how to run this in prod? I'm deploying it on Heroku. On development I'm installing redis with brew package menager, then installing it redis client with npm. How can I set up/mimic this process on remote server on production, f.ex. Heroku?

Comment: You find someone offering Redis as a service, or run it in production yourself, and point your app to it via configuration.

Comment: Could you say more about "run it in production yourself"?

Comment: Not really, there's too much to cover. Get a server/VM, install the software, manage the networking, ...

Comment: You have PaaS heroku redis which is not bad, but I personally prefer RedisLabs, check their service and documentation, it is a good start for anyone involved in Redis in production to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Heroku Redis or RedisCloud provided as addons on heroku.By cost redis cloud may be efficient but I would recommend using heroku Redis as aquarium you can connect and execute all command via cli.